# How to connect GCP filestore with two vpc

Tags: google-cloud-filestore

I need to know if it is possible to create a gcp Filestore on one vpc and connect to it from another vpc without using shared vpc or vpn. Is it expensive to set vpn with the filestore. I mean if the vpn is expensive, I can create one Filestore by vpc instead of using single filestore.
bests,

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is a way, but it involves using HA VPN and cloud interconnects. For our infrastructure, it didn't make sense to use such an expensive architecture for just connecting filestore. In my personal opinion, it is quite an unnecessarily complicated solution.

With that said, you can view the suggested topology link [here](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/topologies#to_peer_vpn_gateways) as well as this [tutorial to setup HA VPN Gateways for connecting GCP VPCs](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-ha-vpn2#creating-ha-gw-2-gw-and-tunnel%5C).

Additional resources:

- [Remote mounting filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/remote-mounting)
- [Cloud interconnect over HA VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect/concepts/ha-vpn-interconnect)